# Aliasing the Copy Directory Command in Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, alias, cp

I frequently copy to a specific directory on my computer. I'm trying to find a way to alias this command in my bashrc. That is, I'd like to define an alias like "cpdraft" and be able to type something like "cpdraft ./Draft.md". Here, cpdraft means something like "cp - dir". In this case, "-" is replaced with "./Draft.md". Is anyone familiar with this kind of alias? In other words, I want to replace an intermediate argument in the command "cp" with a desired input, instead of the usual rightmost one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a bash function. Add this function to your .bashrc file and source it.
e.g. `source .bashrc`. Note the function below copies to Draft.md directory from HOME directory.

```
function cpdraft()
{
    cp "$1" ~/Draft.md
}
```

Your requirements may be to copy to a ./Draft.md in whatever working directory in which case I would suggest always creating the Draft.md directory first if it does not exist:

```
function cpdraft()
{
    [ -d ./Draft.md ] || mkdir ./Draft.md
    cp "$1" ./Draft.md
}
```